# Can you simplify a query while using templated SQL queries

Tags: python, sql, mysql-workbench

Is there a way to simplify this statement as well as access a certain element in the tuple.

```
l = (1,2,3,4)
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 3"
cursor.execute(sql, l)
```

Into something that is more dynamic - I am using this as an example but I have a table with around 30 columns and it seems to be redundant doing it this way. I would also like to update some of the fields when there is a duplicate key. Is there a way to index to a particular value, such as the third one in the list and display it like this

```
l = (1,2,3,4)
sql = "INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('%s') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = {l[2]}"
cursor.execute(sql,l)
```

Where "l" will be something that contains the values that will be inserted into the table

Comment: Do not use `.format()` or other string formatting on SQL queries. It leads to injection vulnerabilities. Pass arguments to `.execute()` instead.

Comment: Don't put the placeholders in quotes when you pass parameters to `cursor.execute()`.

Comment: Is `%s3` a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can construct the placeholder string dynamically based on the length of the tuple.

```
l = (1, 2, 3, 4)
placeholders = ",".join(['%s'] * len(l))
sql = f"INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ({placeholders}) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id = 3"
cursor.execute(sql, l)
```

BTW, don't name your variable `list`, that will replace the stanfard `list()` function.

Comment: Okay thank you, that helps a lot. But how would "id" know which %s to use in the tuple? Would it use the first one? If so, how can I make it reference the 3rd element in the dataset?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I meant to write `id = 3`. The tuple is for all the columns in the table.

Comment: Now does doing id = 3 reference the 3rd element in placeholders? Or does it set the id to 3? I want this part to be dynamic, and change based on the specific placeholder's third elements value

Comment: You need to edit the question and explain what you're really trying to accomplish. What do you mean by "third elements value"? Show an example of the original table contents, and what you expect the final result to be.

Comment: i think that I fixed the second part of the question that I was trying to ask, seeing if I am able to index to a certain place in the tuple.